# Calculating the number of volatile molecules in a container of known volume

Tags: equilibrium, gas-laws, molecules, vapor-pressure

Is it possible to calculate the number of volatile molecules (so only those in the gaseous phase) in a container of known volume, if the vapor pressure of the compound is known? So for example, if you have a container with a volume of $10\ \mathrm{ml}$ containing $3\ \mathrm{ml}$ of a Compound X with a vapor pressure of $10\ \mathrm{mmHg}$ at $\pu{25 ^\circ C}$, what is the number of gaseous molecules of X in the container?

Comment: Yes, this is a do-able calculation.

Comment: We have a policy which states that ‎you should show your thoughts, effort and attempts to understand underlying principles and solve the question. It'll make us certain that ‎we aren't doing your homework for you. ( As homework is considered literal homework, self-study questions, puzzles, worked examples etc.)  Next time,  provide your full reasoning or thoughts on this, otherwise, the  question may get closed.‎ See [Homework](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-chemistry-stack-exchange). This question may get closed  anyway.

Comment: Do you know about [Raoult's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raoult's_law)?